# How can I retrieve HTTP status codes using Angular's $q promises?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I have within my code that makes an `$http.post` to a back end, and of course things can go wrong. If I use the below syntax within angular:

```
$http.post(url).success(function(data, status, headers, config))
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config));
```

If there is an error, I can retrieve the error code using `status` and handle it within the function defined in `error()`. However, if instead I take this approach (which is the one I am in fact using):

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
$http.post(url).success(deferred.resolve).error(deferred.reject);
return deferred.promise;
```

With the second syntax, I have all of my ajax calls within a separate `ServiceJS` directory, and can handle the successes or errors on a case by case basis. For instance, if the second snippet was `Service.MyFunction()` then in the code where I need it I would:

```
Service.MyFunction().then(function() {},
    function(data, status, headers, config) {});
```

However, if I use this code block, `status`, `headers`, `config` are all undefined. My question is how can I retain this syntax but still retrieve the error code?

As an added reference, the back end is a C# Web API project, which would return errors using `return BadRequest();` or the like.

Comment: it's better to handle http errors using interceptors, I can provide an example if you are interested

Comment: That would be helplful, sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
myFunction(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    // you can use .then() instead of .success or .error
    $http.post(url).then(function(successResponse){
         var data = successResponse.data;
         var status = successResponse.status; 
         ...
         deferred.resolve(successResponse);
    }, function(failureResponse){
         var status = failureResponse.status; 
         var config = failureResponse.config; 
         ...            
         deferred.reject(failureResponse);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

well, I'd say it's a good practice and more standard to implement a http interceptor and handle the HTTP errors from there intead of handling the error one by one on each http or resource object, and your code will be located in a single location.

basically, you can segment the actions to take depending on the error status you get for example:

```
angular.module('app').factory('myInterceptor', ['$q',
    function($q){
        return {
            'responseError': function(rejection){
                switch(rejection.status){
                    case 0:
                        //'No connection, is the internet down?'
                        break;
                    case 422:
                        // error
                        break;
                    case 484:
                        // error
                        break;
                    default:
                        // message rejection.status, rejection.statusText
                        break;
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    }
    ]);
```

Comment: Hmm doesn't this handle all like errors in the same fashion? I'm concerned about, for instance, if on a page where you have to log in you can either get a `Conflict` or `BadRequest`or something of the like, and then based on the error that page gets back, it will alert the user in some fashion

Comment: I can see the value in handling all errors in a like fashion, but is there a reason I shouldn't be handling them on a case by case basis if the user needs to know what is wrong?

Comment: Actually for alerts the users, you can create a customized directive to display the rejection message or any other message library like toaster, the reason that that approach is widely adopted is because you reduce drastically the amount of boilerplate code and also encourage convention over configuration you can send an specific error message from the server and do an specific action on the client

Comment: I think both cases are right... you might want one general area for handling errors... maybe for things like logging them back to the server? or a global error div that appears at the bottom like a toast message. But if you have one function and get a certain error and need to display that to the user, yes, you can handle that in your controller when the service returns a promise; I'm thinking for things like "the password you entered was invalid" or something just below the password field (since it's tied to a particular view).

Comment: @jack.the.ripper I definitely see the use with toasters and alerts,  and may end up adopting this for much of the work now that I think about it. But there are a few cases where page specific error handling is necessary, in my case

Comment: @mike agree on implementing custom error handlers, but just be aware those implementations should be the exceptions and not to be the norm

Answer (score 0):

`$http` is already returning a promise, so why not use that one?

```
function myFunction() {
  return $http.post(url);
}

// ...

myFunction().success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  // ...
});

... or ...

myFunction().then(...);
```

The promises returned from `$http` have the methods `success` and `error` in addition to the other promise methods. Read more at [Angular docs for $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).